# Laravel not sending mail inside scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, email, scheduled-tasks

I've created a command to send mail, it works fine when executing the command from console, and emails are sent:

`php artisan loans:notify`

Then I've created task inside the scheduler like this:

```php
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
  {
    $schedule->command('loans:notify')->hourlyAt(24);
  }
```

then executed `php artisan schedule:work`, and the scheduler executes the task with outpu:

```
[2021-05-15T19:24:00+02:00] Execution #1 output:
Running scheduled command: "d:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.11-win32-vc15-x64\php.exe" "artisan" loans:notify > "NUL" 2>&1
```

but the emails are not sent.

I've tried it with a job, and it is the same, I've add logging when sending mail, the logging part works, but still emails are not sent.

Here the mail sending part:

```php
 public function handle()
  {
    $movements = BookInstanceMovement::where('borrow_returned', NULL)->whereDate('borrow_end', '<', Carbon::now())->get();
    foreach ($movements as $movement) {
      try {
        echo "SENDING MAIL\n";
        echo "to " . $movement->user->email . "\n";
        echo "book " . $movement->book_instance->book->title . "\n";
        Mail::to($movement->user)->send(new LateLoanMail($movement->book_instance->book->title));
      } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        echo $th->getMessage();
      }
    }
  }
```

**Update**:

I've found out that commands inside scheduler may not work in Windows, because it executes it like this

`"d:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.11-win32-vc15-x64\php.exe" "artisan" loans:notify > "NUL" 2>&1`

when tried to execute it on console it gives error:

`Out-File: FileStream was asked to open a device that was not a file. For support for devices like 'com1:' or 'lpt1:', call CreateFile, then use the FileStream constructors that take an  OS handle as an IntPtr.`

But using Jobs, it outputs logging without sending the emails.

**Update:**

Executing `php artisan schedule:run`, works and sends emails, is `php artisan schedule:work` queue emails?

Comment: run: php artisan loans:notify, and see if it log anything else?

Comment: @ChinhNguyen it works fine, outputs the log, and sends the emails.

Answer (score 0):

Im late to the party but I'm also having a similar issue. All my Mail works on Vapor using Mailgun when certain events happen. However when creating a command to send reminder emails no mail is fired when vapor runs the cron task but it updates the DB to say it's all good but if I execute my command manually via the vapor UI or command line mail sends.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30260553)